# Spring Boot 2.0.4 + Hibernate 5- fetching lazy collections outside controller scope without invoking getters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I am having a spring boot web application with hibernate implementation of spring JPA. I am one-many relationship between my entities using join column annotation. To achieve this, Technology entity has a member which is List. I have marked this List to be lazy initialized. Everything is fine, but once the control moves outside controller, hibernate is firing calls to lazy collection(List) without having invoked for it. This is causing huge delay in loading the web page. Not sure why is hibernate firing lazy collections outside controller scope. I have tried using Hibernate.initialize and Maven bytecode enhancement plugin, but nothing seems to work. Please help

### Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EmergentTechnologies")
public class EmergentTechnology implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ETID")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Artifact> artifacts;

@Entity
@Table(name="Artifacts")
public class Artifact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Analyst")
    private String analyst;

    @Column(name="ArtifactType")
    private String artifactType;
```

### application properties

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
logging.level.com.boeing.etl=INFO
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>    
                            <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                                    </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/artifacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmergentTechnology>> getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        logger.info("Enter getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech");
        int emergentTechId=Integer.parseInt(id);
        List<EmergentTechnology> emergentTechnology = emergingTechLibService.getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech(emergentTechId);
        logger.info("Exit getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(emergentTechnology);
    }
```

### Service

```
@Override
    public List<EmergentTechnology> getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech(int emergentTechId) {
        logger.info("Enter getAllArtifactsByEmergentTech");
        List<EmergentTechnology> emergentTechnologies=emergentTechnologyRepository.getAllArtifactsById(emergentTechId);
        //Optional<EmergentTechnology> emergentTechnology=emergentTechnologyRepository.findById(emergentTechId);
        //emergentTechnologies.add(emergentTechnology.get());
        logger.info("After calling findAllArtifactsById()");
        return emergentTechnologies;
    }
```

### Repository

```
@Override
    public List<EmergentTechnology> getAllArtifactsById(int emergentTechId) {
        logger.info("Enter getEmergentTechnologies");
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<EmergentTechnology> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EmergentTechnology.class);
        Root<EmergentTechnology> root = criteriaQuery.from(EmergentTechnology.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Integer>get("id"), emergentTechId));
        List<EmergentTechnology> emergingTechnologies = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        logger.info("Exit getEmergentTechnologies");
        return emergingTechnologies;
    }
```

Loading all Artifacts when control moves out of controller (as per application logs)

Comment: The getter is called indirectly by the serialization process. Your `List<EmergentTechnology>` is getting serialized to JSON so getters for all fields (including the `artifacts` field) are called

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having the 1+N problem. You can make hibernate load all data in one query. To do that you could use fetch join with your criteria.

```
@Override
public List<EmergentTechnology> getAllArtifactsById(int emergentTechId) {
    logger.info("Enter getEmergentTechnologies");
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EmergentTechnology> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EmergentTechnology.class);
    Root<EmergentTechnology> root = criteriaQuery.from(EmergentTechnology.class);

    // NEW CODE 
    root.fetch("artifacts", JoinType.INNER);

    criteriaQuery.select(root);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Integer>get("id"), emergentTechId));
    List<EmergentTechnology> emergingTechnologies = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    logger.info("Exit getEmergentTechnologies");
    return emergingTechnologies;
}
```

Another option to have hibernate get all data with one query is to use a [named entity graph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph).

While I'm not sure this will solve all your problems, you should still see a performance improvement.

Also, based on the nature of your data (seems to me it is a set of information that won't be big and won't change much or often) you could take great advantage of [spring caching](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) which would be perfect for your use case.

One more option is using [hibernate query cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/caching/Caching.html).

Comment: I like the idea of spring caching but caching based on id is not usually a good idea due to the diversity of values. Of course it will depend on the number of records contained in the EmergentTechnologies

Comment: Based on the name of entities it does sound like the dataset will be small, dozens, maybe hundreds of entries. That is not a big enough number to be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

One thing before answering: don't return an entity as response of a rest service because you are coupling the consumer of your service to your data base hence is a bad practice.

Now the answer: When your controller has as return a List wrapped in a ResponseEntity. @ResponseBody annotation means is that the returned value of the method will constitute the body of the HTTP response. As no Java objects are allowed in the response they must be serialized into format suitable for REST applications, namely JSON or XML (this will depend on the values of the produces attribute of the RequestMapping annotation, and on the content type accepted by the client). Due to this serilization process getter methods from the EmergentTechnology objects (managed by Hibernate, so they are proxied) will be called. This call will cause the fetching of artifacts list.

So what you have to do is map your entity into an VO (avoiding the couple) in the service EmergingTechLibService (I recommend [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/)) avoiding to invoke to the getter of artifacts